# IF Statement in excel for dates not bring up correct Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have made a formula in excel that partially works, apart from the `Due to expire` part

```
('General Training '!H3<$G$1-1003,"Due to Expire")
```

It is returning `FALSE` could someone point me in the right direction please ?

If the cell is blank do nothing which works.

If the date `H3` is less than TODAY($G1) - 1003 then `training required` which works
IF (H3) Greater than TODAY($G1) "Training Complete" Also Works

```
=IF(ISBLANK('General Training '!H3),"",IF('General Training '!H3<$G$1-1097,"Training Required",IF('General Training '!H3<$G$1-1003,"Due to Expire",IF('General Training '!H3>$G$1,"Training Complete"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the Cell `H3` and the `-1003`, the calculation is doing `H3<$G$1` and then `-1003`

Wrap the `$G$1-1003` in brackets, like below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('General Training '!H3),"",IF('General Training '!H3<$G$1-1097,"Training Required",IF('General Training '!H3<($G$1-1003),"Due to Expire",IF('General Training '!H3>$G$1,"Training Complete"))))
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried this and have realised i also need it to say training complete if it is greater than TODAY() but less than TODAY() - 1002 is that possible Thanks